# Importing special characters from txt-file (Python 3.3)

Tags: csv, python-3.x, ascii

I am reading data from a text file.

```
import csv
BildeDB = []
with open('bilder.txt', newline='') as inputfile:
    for row in csv.reader(inputfile):
        BildeDB.append(row)
```

The text file contains some Norwegian characters, causing a problem on import of the characters Æ, Ø and Å. They are replaced with A~ and A...

Searching around stackoverflow suggested this solution: adding

```
sys.setdefaultencoding('latin-1')
```

at the very top, but that apparently isn't a valid attribute:

```
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'setdefaultencoding'
```

Any other ideas on how to import with greater success?

Comment: I believe open in text mode can take an encoding parameter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `encoding` param of the `open()` function.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Added with open('bilder.txt', newline='', encoding='utf-8') as inputfile: and that seems to work!

Answer (score 0):

+1 for jwalker. The reason is that a read from a file opened in the text mode must produce unicode strings. For that, encoding od the file must be given.